# Numpy.NumpyArray has no attribute Read

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am trying to test a Convolution Neural Network with images that are stored in a folder within the root project directory. I have some code that is giving me an error and I am not sure why or where exactly the error is coming from. I will have the code and the full trace back of the error:

the code(there are 6 jpg images in the folder)

```
import os
for testing_image in os.listdir('testing_images/'):
    full_detector('testing_images/' + testing_image)
```

full error traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\deep_learning_1\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2546     try:
-> 2547         fp.seek(0)
   2548     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-68ab37d51b76> in <module>()
      4 import os
      5 for testing_image in os.listdir('testing_images/'):
----> 6     full_detector('testing_images/' + testing_image)

<ipython-input-119-a1a8a7870ff5> in full_detector(image_path)
      3 def full_detector(image_path):
      4     pred_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
----> 5     dog_breed = Resnet_Predict_Breed(pred_image)
      6     if dog_detector(image_path):
      7         print('this is dog with the breed : {}'.format(breed))

<ipython-input-118-c02818bc5801> in Resnet_Predict_Breed(img_path)
      2 ### and returns the dog breed that is predicted by the model.
      3 def Resnet_Predict_Breed(img_path):
----> 4     bottleneck_feature = extract_Resnet50(path_to_tensor(img_path))
      5     predicted_vector = resnet_model.predict(bottleneck_feature)
      6     return dog_names[np.argmax(predicted_vector)]

<ipython-input-18-3693dbe72dab> in path_to_tensor(img_path)
      4 def path_to_tensor(img_path):
      5     # loads RGB image as PIL.Image.Image type
----> 6     img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
      7     # convert PIL.Image.Image type to 3D tensor with shape (224, 224, 3)
      8     x = image.img_to_array(img)

~\Anaconda3\envs\deep_learning_1\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py in load_img(path, grayscale, target_size, interpolation)
    347         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    348                           'The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL.')
--> 349     img = pil_image.open(path)
    350     if grayscale:
    351         if img.mode != 'L':

~\Anaconda3\envs\deep_learning_1\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2547         fp.seek(0)
   2548     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
-> 2549         fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
   2550         exclusive_fp = True
   2551 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
dog_breed = Resnet_Predict_Breed(pred_image)
```

Use `image_path` instead, and no need to use `cv2.imread`.